# SVEN AVR 2000 LCD Стабилизатор напряжения сети - ничего не стабилизирует

Tags: железо

Купил стабилизатор сети SVEN AVR 2000 LCD.

На экранчиках пляшет "входное напряжение" и "выходное напряжение".

И они одинаковые всё время,

- 226-227
- 228-228
- 223-224

Разница в единицу.

Я думал он будет на выход тупо выдавать 230 или 220. Разве не так должно быть?

Comment: Разве такие вопросы относятся к тематике сайта?

Comment: мне кажется, пока нет ru.hardware, всё что связано с компом относится сюда. разве не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Назначение SVEN AVR-2000 LCD - это защита от повышенного входного и выходного напряжения, короткого замыкания, высокочастотных и высоковольтных помех. Что касается напряжения, то в его характеристиках указано: `Выходное напряжение, В ~220 ± 8 %`. Это 220 ± 17.6 В, так что все в пределах допуска. Иными словами, если входное напряжение находится в диапазоне от 202 до 237 (приблизительно), то столько же он и выдаст. А вот при выходе за этот диапазон - напряжение будет стабилизироваться.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Просто в магазине светил 230 на входе и столько же на выходе. Я думал будет 230 на выходе держать... не зря же в него запаяны все эти стабилизаторы и конденсаторы...

Comment: @abrahamLinkoln В магазине одно напряжение сети, у вас в доме - другое, вот и результат. А в целом и то и другое в пределах допуска.Для наших сетей это нормально.

Comment: просто, у меня горит всё подряд, упс поплыл - батареи сгорели, сотовый nokia перестал заряжаться нормально, сгорел бп на коме 500 ват, chieftek, я за-пониковал, что всё горит со скачков, и приобрел....